# How to save and replay a trajectory generated with moveit

Tags: ros, c++, moveit, move-group-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am using moveit's move_group_interface in C++ to generate a trajectory between two NamedTargets for Youbot. Everything works fine including visualization in RViz. However, on repeated execution, the trajectories look slightly different for the same set of targets. So, my question is:  Is there any way one can save a trajectory so that it can be reused later on? I have tried saving the "plan.trajectory_", but it doesn't seem to work. Details of current setup is given below.

Robot: **Youbot** 
Planner: **OMPL/RRTkConfigDefault**  
Interface: **moveit/move_group_interface in C++**
Logic/Sequence Used:

1. Set Start State to Current State
2. Set a Named Target
3. Visualize the plan in Rviz
4. Execute the plan

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271263/how-to-save-and-replay-a-trajectory-generated-with-moveit/) by [ani](https://answers.ros.org/users/26307/ani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-09-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can write a script to save the generated plan. When you command a target position in MoveIt!, you can access the trajectory using moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup::Plan ([API](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/structmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup_1_1Plan.html)). You can save this trajectory as a YAML file and read it next time you are executing the motion, use this Plan for execution. Unfortunately, there is no available function which performs this action.

---

Originally posted by [pk](https://answers.ros.org/users/22577/pk/) with karma: 76 on 2018-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NYs](https://answers.ros.org/users/14291/nys/) on 2018-01-03**:
in case you're wondering how to save a yaml file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470665/how-can-i-write-data-in-yaml-format-in-a-file

**Comment by [pranavb104](https://answers.ros.org/users/38753/pranavb104/) on 2019-01-21**:
Is there a reference for dumping yaml in c++?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got this working for python on UR5 in Gazebo

```
import yaml
import os
    
plan = group.plan()
        
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'saved_trajectories', 'plan.yaml')
with open(file_path, 'w') as file_save:
    yaml.dump(plan, file_save, default_flow_style=True)
        
with open(file_path, 'r') as file_open:
    loaded_plan = yaml.load(file_open)
        
group.execute(loaded_plan)
```

---

Originally posted by [NYs](https://answers.ros.org/users/14291/nys/) with karma: 11 on 2018-01-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pranavb104](https://answers.ros.org/users/38753/pranavb104/) on 2019-01-21**:
Is there a reference for dumping yaml in c++?

**Comment by [Diliban](https://answers.ros.org/users/67402/diliban/) on 2021-01-08**:
Is there a way to save the trajectory using RViz?